# How can I unshrink column headers of one2many tree view in odoo 14?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-14

Odoo shrinks the column header based on datatypes and when there are many fields in one2many tree view. the columns are shrinked.

When I checked the file list_editable_renderer.js under web folder
There are these constants for column width

```
 const fixedWidths = {
            boolean: '70px',
            date: '92px',
            datetime: '146px',
            float: '92px',
            integer: '74px',
            monetary: '104px',
        };
```

I am just not able to solve this issue.

[image: One2many]

I tried changing few of the JS code, None seem to be working.
Any help or guidance would be of a great help

Comment: You can add a custom CSS to set the minimum width for those fields. You can set a class attribute (`no_shrink`) on the tree view then, in CSS, use that class to target the tree and use the `data-name` attribute to target a specif field. For example, you can target the `tax_id` field in sale order by using the following selector `.no_shrink th[data-name="tax_id"]`

Comment: @Kenly, Thank you first of all for your time. I need to set custom width in the CSS right? .no_shrink th[data-name="tax_id"]{width: 1000px;} like this?

Comment: You need to set the `min-width`. For example `.word_break th[data-name="tax_id"]{min-width: 50px;}`.

Comment: Did you succeed to set the ``min-width``

Comment: Hi Kenly, Here is how I have tried it.

Comment: .ef_saletree th[data-name="x_customer_order_length"]{min-width: 50px;} This I have defined in css file

Comment: Since Its a tree view of Sale order I have given it like this - <tree
                                    string="Sales Order Lines"
                                    class="ef_saletree"
                                    editable="bottom"
                                >

Comment: Still it is not showing any effect on tree view column, the customer_order_length is in a custom module, inheriting sale order line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom CSS to set the minimum width for those fields. You can set a class attribute on the tree view then, in CSS, use that class to target the tree and use the `data-name` attribute to target a specif field.

By default, `min-width` is set to `74px`, use `!important` to force the new value.

To show `Customer length` label, try length of `130px`.

***Example:***

```
.ef_saletree th[data-name="x_customer_order_length"]{min-width: 130px !important;}
```

Comment: Thank you for the efforts that you have shown. .ef_saletree [data-name="x_customer_order_length"]{width: 130px !important;}. This did the trick Kenly. Really appreciate your efforts. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: I'm glad to help